# refuse to cp/rsync/etc some files with strange characters

Tags: unicode, cifs

We have a Windows server with filenames containing unusual characters. For exemple `picture.jpg` (the unusual character is between the `e` and the `.jpg`).

We mount it with `mount  -t cifs  -o 'ro,iocharset=utf8'  //server/source-share  /dest-path`
`iocharset=utf8` can be removed, it changes nothing.

When we use `ls` everything works. But cp/rsync and other commands fail on those files:
`cp  -r  /dest-path  /tmp` --> `cp: cannot stat '/dest-path/picture .jpg': No such file or directory`
You can note the special character is displayed as a space.

With rsync the error is `file has vanished: "/dest-path/picture .jpg"` (with a space too).

Any idea to overcome this behaviour?

UPDATE: tried `rsync  -rhicov` and `rsync  -av` as suggested. No improvement, as expected because those options has nothing to do with this problem.
`rsync  -av  /dest-path/*  \tmp` gives the same result (`file has vanished`)
`find /dest-path -name "*.jpg" -ls` works correctly.
`find   /dest-path  -print0  |  rsync  -av  --files-from=-  --from0  ./  /tmp` gives the error `rsync: link_stat "/dest-path/picture .jpg" failed: No such file or directory (2)`
Just tested `tar  czf  archive.tgz  /dest-path`: error `File removed before we read it`

BEWARE: `ls` and `find` display the filenames, but the special characters are displayed as spaces (I just checked with an hex editor). Some other special characters are correctly handled, and work correctly with rsync.
So this can be a problem within the CIFS module.

Comment: Try `rsync -rhicov` and the other options mentioned [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/rsync-can%27t-copy-certain-files-with-unusual-characters-while-cp-can-827462/).

Comment: What happens if you try the following commands? `rsync -av /dest-path  /tmp` ;  What happens if you try `rsync -av /dest-path/picture*  /tmp` (and let the system identify the strange character via an automatic method). Finally, what do you see from `find /dest-path -name "*.jpg" -ls`